# Imprimir uma variavel de Javascript em Input html

Tags: javascript, html, html5, aplicação-web

```
  <script>
    function Sumar() {
        var n7 = document.getElementById('txtN7').value; /*Fator tempo*/
        var n8 = n7.replace(',','.');   
        var cem = (n8)/4; /*Calculo de fator*/
        var n1 = document.getElementById('txtN1').value; /*100%*/
        var n2 = document.getElementById('txtN2').value; /*101%*/

        var suma = ((parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2))*cem); /*Resultado somenta dos valores de 100 e 101*/

        var n3 = document.getElementById('txtN3').value; /*95-99%*/
        var n4 = document.getElementById('txtN4').value; /*85%-94%*/
        var n5 = document.getElementById('txtN5').value; /*75%-84*/
        var n6 = document.getElementById('txtN6').value; /*50%-74%*/
        var n9 = document.getElementById('txtN9').value; /*No Match*/

        var suma1 = (((parseInt(n3) + parseInt(n4)+ parseInt(n5)+parseInt(n6)+parseInt(n9))*n8)+suma);
        document.write(suma1);
    /* alert("Número estimado em horas: "+suma1) */
       }
</script>
```

Boa tarde pessoal!!!
Preciso criar um "Input Text" do Html5 para imprimir a variável suma1 do javascript.
utilizei o document.write mais ao clicar no botão ele faz um tipo refresh e mostra o valor em uma página em branco. Desde já agradeço!!!

```
<input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="Calcular Horas Tradução">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu problema é que você está utilizando o document.write, este comando vai substituir todo o conteúdo da sua pagina.
Você deve criar um div para "imprimir" o resultado, veja o exemplo abaixo:

```
function Sumar() {
  var n7 = document.getElementById('txtN7').value; /*Fator tempo*/
  var n8 = n7.replace(',','.');   
  var cem = (n8)/4; /*Calculo de fator*/
  var n1 = document.getElementById('txtN1').value; /*100%*/
  var n2 = document.getElementById('txtN2').value; /*101%*/

  var suma = ((parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2))*cem); /*Resultado somenta dos valores de 100 e 101*/

  var n3 = document.getElementById('txtN3').value; /*95-99%*/
  var n4 = document.getElementById('txtN4').value; /*85%-94%*/
  var n5 = document.getElementById('txtN5').value; /*75%-84*/
  var n6 = document.getElementById('txtN6').value; /*50%-74%*/
  var n9 = document.getElementById('txtN9').value; /*No Match*/

  var suma1 = (((parseInt(n3) + parseInt(n4)+ parseInt(n5)+parseInt(n6)+parseInt(n9))*n8)+suma);

  document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = suma1;
  /* alert("Número estimado em horas: "+suma1) */
}
```

O comando document.write é substituído por document.getElementById("resultado").innerHTML = suma1;

E você deve criar um div com este id conforme abaixo

```
<input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="Calcular Horas Tradução">
<div id="resultado"></div>
```

Comment: marcelo é quase isso que eu quero..... só que ele está imprimindo em uma div..... eu preciso que seja em uma caixa de texto> 

    <input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="Calcular Horas Tradução">
<input type="text" id="resultado"></input>

Comment: Neste caso voce deve mudar o comando para document.getElementById("resultado").value = suma1; e criar o input desta forma <input type="text" id="resultado">

Comment: Valeuuuu!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!   era isso msm que eu precisava!!!!!!!
Muito obrigado.... sou novo em Javascript e todo mundo web....
To apanhando um monte, rsrsrsrss

Answer (score 0):

Utilize `document.getElementById('id-do-campo').value = suma1;`

Dessa forma o valor da variável `suma1` será adicionando no atributo `value` do `input`

---

Para criar dinamicamente, basta utilizar `document.createElement("input")`, depois é só atribuir o valor na propriedade `value`

**Exemplo:**

```js
function Sumar(element) {
  var n7 = document.getElementById('txtN7').value; /*Fator tempo*/
  var n8 = n7.replace(',', '.');
  var cem = (n8) / 4; /*Calculo de fator*/
  var n1 = document.getElementById('txtN1').value; /*100%*/
  var n2 = document.getElementById('txtN2').value; /*101%*/

  var suma = ((parseInt(n1) + parseInt(n2)) * cem); /*Resultado somenta dos valores de 100 e 101*/

  var n3 = document.getElementById('txtN3').value; /*95-99%*/
  var n4 = document.getElementById('txtN4').value; /*85%-94%*/
  var n5 = document.getElementById('txtN5').value; /*75%-84*/
  var n6 = document.getElementById('txtN6').value; /*50%-74%*/
  var n9 = document.getElementById('txtN9').value; /*No Match*/

  var suma1 = (((parseInt(n3) + parseInt(n4) + parseInt(n5) + parseInt(n6) + parseInt(n9)) * n8) + suma);
  

  /* Cria input e adiciona o valor da variável */
  let input = document.createElement("input");
  input.value = suma1;
  
  /* Inclui o input no elemento body */
  document.body.appendChild( input )
}
```

```html
<input type="hidden" id="txtN1" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN2" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN3" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN4" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN5" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN6" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN7" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN8" value="1" />
<input type="hidden" id="txtN9" value="1" />

<input type="button" onclick="Sumar();" value="Calcular Horas Tradução">
```

O `document.write` servirá para apagar todo o conteúdo da tela e substituir pelo valor indicado.

Comment: Não sei se lhe estou entendendo mal.... ( desculpe sou novo em Html/Javascript).

O valor da variável suma1 ( Javascript) está correto só que antes ele mostrava o valor em um alert. eu preciso que o valor seja mostrado em um input text ( uma caixa de texto). 
 
Obrigado.. por responder!!!! Sua explicação mostra o valor da variavel suma no input?

Comment: @RodrigoHackzExploitz Sim. É só clicar no botão "Executar" para testar o código.